# Print Variable and date variable that corresponds with the outlier detected.

Tags: r

I'm trying to print so I can see the date variable that corresponds with the variable i'm running my double MAD function on. I'm coming from SAS and a new programmer for R. I'm calling the variables from a dataset.

```
DoubleMAD <- function(x, zero.mad.action="warn"){
  # The zero.mad.action determines the action in the event of an MAD of zero.
  # Possible values: "stop", "warn", "na" and "warn and na".
  x         <- x[!is.na(x)]
  m         <- median(x)
  abs.dev   <- abs(x - m)
  left.mad  <- median(abs.dev[x<=m])
  right.mad <- median(abs.dev[x>=m])
  if (left.mad == 0 || right.mad == 0){
    if (zero.mad.action == "stop") stop("MAD is 0")
    if (zero.mad.action %in% c("warn", "warn and na")) warning("MAD is 0")
    if (zero.mad.action %in% c(  "na", "warn and na")){
      if (left.mad  == 0) left.mad  <- NA
      if (right.mad == 0) right.mad <- NA
    }
  }
  return(c(left.mad, right.mad))
}

DoubleMADsFromMedian <- function(x, zero.mad.action="warn"){
  # The zero.mad.action determines the action in the event of an MAD of zero.
  # Possible values: "stop", "warn", "na" and "warn and na".
  two.sided.mad <- DoubleMAD(x, zero.mad.action)
  m <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  x.mad <- rep(two.sided.mad[1], length(x))
  x.mad[x > m] <- two.sided.mad[2]
  mad.distance <- abs(x - m) / x.mad
  mad.distance[x==m] <- 0
  return(mad.distance)
}
DoubleMAD(x)
DoubleMAD(test_dataset_double_meidan$Sales)
```

``

```
`print(test_dataset_double_meidan$Sales[DoubleMADsFromMedian(test_dataset_double_meidan$Sales) > 3])
```

Any help would be appreciated.